# docker bash: mysql: command not found

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, mariadb

After getting the docker pull, if you proceed as follows, you will get a statement that it cannot be found.

I want to solve this problem.

```bash
docker pull mariadb
.
.
.
docker exec -it mariadb /bin/bash

mysql -u root -p

bash: mysql: command not found
```

I would like to know why the error occurred.

I want mysql to run.

next syntax

- Enter Passoword

Comment: apt-get install vim
I did.

Comment: what does vim have to do with mysql? :) I hope you are not blindly running commands not understanding what they do? There are plenty of tutorials on how to get mysql running withing a docker image, or mariadb ... are you following any particular tutorial for this?

Comment: I followed the blog, but it was written as mysql on the blog, so I followed it exactly.

I thought too much of a simple problem.

thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

This docker image has no mysql client installed by default. you can use `mariadb -uroot -p`

Comment: I followed the blog, but it was written as mysql on the blog, so I followed it exactly.

I thought too much of a simple problem.

thank you. :)

Comment: @baulkim upvoute his answer!

Answer (score 5):

As specified in MariaDB docker documentation, since mariadb:11 (mariadb:latest) has no `mysql` executable or symlink. `mariadb` is the official command line executable. Use of a `mysql` named executable will result in a deprecation warning.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-11-0-1-release-notes/#docker-official-images

To keep compatibility with existing scripts you can fix the docker image version number to a previous release that supports the `mysql` command, like `mariadb:10.4`

To use the latest version, you should rename calls to `mysql` command in any related script to `mariadb`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an older version that does have is:

`mariadb:10.5`

Or work round it like they suggest above.

It's annoying when you have builds / instructions using `mariadb:latest` and they changed it!